# HTMLで画像と文字が重なってしまう。

Tags: html, css

`<div id="study_001">`をまとまりとして、
`<img>`や下の`<ul>`との間に余白を作りたいのですが、
重なってしまいます。

divはブロック要素だと思うのですが、
spanのみを中身にもつdivは高さを持たないということでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**[HTML]**

```
<img src="images/001_blue.png" alt="">

<div id="study_001">
<span id="margin">margin</span><span id="border">border</span><span id="padding">padding</span>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>HTMLとCSS</li>
  <li>要素</li>
  <li>margin｜border｜padding</li>
  <li>float</li>
  <!--...-->
```

**[CSS]**

```
img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  float: left;
}

#study_001{
  clear: left;
}

#margin{
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  background: #f98;
}

#border{
  border-left: 3px #fff solid;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 2px;
  background: #988;
  margin: 0;
}

#padding{
  background: #498;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

開発者ツールで見るとわかりますが、span に指定した padding が親要素 `#study_001` の高さに反映されていません。もちろん、上下 margin も反映されていません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

インライン要素の上下位置や間隔は**行の高さ**、つまり `line-height` を基準に計算されます。ですから padding や border を指定した場合、その部分が親要素からはみ出したり、前後の行と重なってしまうことになります。

ブロック要素のレイアウトが「高さと幅を持つ箱を並べる」のに対し、インライン要素では「中にあるテキストを流し込む」といったイメージでしょうか。

```css
div {
  line-height: 1;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 20px;
}

span {
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 128, 128, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>じゅげむ　じゅげむ　ごこうのすりきれ</span>
</div>
```

代わりの方法としては

- padding ではなく line-height で高さを確保する
- `display: inline-block`（行内に配置されるブロック要素のような感じなので、ボックスの幅や高さを持ち、折り返しで分断されることがない）
- `display: table-cell`
- `display: block` + `float: left`

等々。どれも使い方によってはデメリットがありますから、用途に合わせて選んでください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！divの子要素であるインライン要素（今の場合span）のmarginやpaddingは、親であるdivの高さ・幅には影響を与えないという理解でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @forest 上下方向のmarginやpaddingはその通りです。親だけでなく、隣接する要素との間隔が広がることもありません。左右方向のmarginやpaddingは機能します。

Comment: なるほど！ブロック要素同士だと上下方向のmarginやpaddingは影響するのでしょうか？

Comment: @forest 自身がブロック要素であれば上下方向のmarginやpaddingがレイアウトに影響する、自身がインライン要素であれば影響しない、ということです。レイアウトの基本的な仕組みは、例えばこちらのサイトが参考になるかと思います。ぜひ最初から最後まで読んでみてください。 http://webdesignrecipes.com/css-visual-formating-model/

Comment: ありがとうございます！少しずつ読んでみます。